# free open online projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, open-source

another victim of the recession here. got tired of reading up on c# stuff and i want to work on a project now.

looking for projects i can work on where we can keep in touch online. i have a couple of years of c# experience.
source forge seemed cool but can't be browsed by programming language :/

so if you are working on something and need some dot net C# help (for free), lemme know... or a website where geeks like me can get together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net) can be still browsed by programming language, although it is not as easy as it was in the old interface.

To do so, from the main page click on Find Software, then a general topic or Display All, and then Display: Filters.  In the Filter area, use the comboboxes to add a filter to Require Programming Language C# and click Apply.

Comment: I knew this used to be something you could do from Sourceforge; I didn't know it had been changed.

Comment: cool i'm already getting my hands dirty in a project now. i've finished brushing up on application dev and moving on to website dev.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an open source C# project: [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).  You might also check here: [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/)

Comment: completley forgot about mono. testing it for compatibility first. then i'll start more complex stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about situation .

There are lot of such sites. You just have to search for them. Few of them are :

- http://www.8kmiles.com/
- http://www.rentacoder.com/

As for as posting such questions. Keep the questions programming related on the site. see the FAQ - https://stackoverflow.com/faq and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about the job situation.  You may try some of the popular projects like [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com) or [Autofac](http://groups.google.com/group/autofac?pli=1) and potentially a lateral lead may appear.  Wish I could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to evaluate this?  http://www.tribewanted.com/

It looks to be trading coding for a holiday in Fiji.  See what you think.